# Activity with two fragments with draggable bar in between to allow resizing of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a project where I have an activity, which has two fragments loaded in.

I have this working except I want to put a touch bar in the middle between the two fragments, that will allow the user to drag the bar which would then resize the each fragment, i.e. make one fragment grow the other fragment shrink.

Below is the current layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <fragment android:name="com.company.myapp.LoginFragment"
        android:id="@+id/login_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <fragment android:name="com.company.myapp.ApiFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/api_fragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a specific way to do this in Android via an API or will I need to add my own and use touch/drag listeners to resize appropriately.

Comment: Just add a View and attach a listener through which you can increase/decrease size of each fragment.

Comment: I thought that would be most likely the way to go, but was hoping there bit a handy simple Android API that would do it

Comment: Nope! Unfortunately there isn't any yet. :/